# How to get an array from Firebase database efficiently?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get an array out of this:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
const first = db.collection('comments').orderBy('rating').limit(25);
```

Is there a function that "first" has that just lets me get the data out of the box? I tried printing the object, but it's obfuscated or something; all the field names are random letters.

Up to now, I've been iterating through using a Promise, but it's getting annoying quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Up to now, I've been iterating through using a Promise, but it's getting annoying quick.

You can't avoid using the promise returned by `get()`, as shown in the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#querysnapshot).  You will, at the very least, need to use `await` or `then` on it to wait for the async query to complete, then look at the [QuerySnapshot](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/querysnapshot) it yielded by that promise.

If you want just the first item in the results set, you can simply use the first item in the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/querysnapshot#docs) array property of the QuerySnapshot.